# Invalid DTO posted throws exception

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-2.2, abp

Invalid DTO posted to MVC endpoint throws an exception, expecting it to record it in ModelState.

How according to Abp should such exception be handled gracefully?

I see [ABP documentation on validating DTOs](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects) where it throws the exception for invalid models, but how to pass the error messages to a  view.

Using

1. aspnetboilerplate sample for MVC + .NET Core
2. Abp package version 4.3
3. Net Core 2.2

What I did:

Added a DTO

```
public class ExamDtoBaseTmp
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Can't add without a name")]

        [StringLength(EntityCommons.MaxExamNameLength,ErrorMessage ="Keep is short")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Description is needed")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Added a POST endpoint that accepted above model

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ExamDtoBaseTmp model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Submitted empty form and got below exception:

```
AbpValidationException: Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.

    Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.ThrowValidationError() in MethodInvocationValidator.cs
    Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.Validate() in MethodInvocationValidator.cs
    Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Validation.AbpValidationActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) in AbpValidationActionFilter.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    Nivra.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtTokenMiddleware+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<UseJwtTokenMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext() in JwtTokenMiddleware.cs

                    await next();

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) Nivra.Web.Startup.Startup+<>c+<<Configure>b__4_1>d.MoveNext() in Startup.cs

                    await next();

Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Castle.Facilities.Logging;
using Abp.AspNetCore;
using Abp.Castle.Logging.Log4Net;
using Nivra.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Nivra.Configuration;
using Nivra.Identity;
using Nivra.Web.Resources;
using Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using System.Linq;
using Abp.Extensions;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal;
using Nivra.OnlineExam.Models;
using Nivra.OnlineExam.Service;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Nivra.Web.Startup
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private const string _defaultCorsPolicyName = "localhost";
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _appConfiguration = env.GetAppConfiguration();
        }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.Configure<ExamDatabaseSettings>(
                _appConfiguration.GetSection(nameof(ExamDatabaseSettings))
            );

            services.AddSingleton<IExamDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ExamDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

            services.AddSingleton<ExamService>();

            // MVC
            services.AddMvc(
                options =>
                options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName))
                //options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute())

            );

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(c =>
            {
                c.RootPath = "wwwroot/dist";
            });


            IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
            AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);


            services.AddSignalR();


            // Configure CORS for angular2 UI
            services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddPolicy(
                    _defaultCorsPolicyName,
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        //.WithOrigins(
                        //    // App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address separated by comma.
                        //    _appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                        //        .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        //        .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                        //        .ToArray()
                        //)
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                )
            );

            // Swagger - Enable this line and the related lines in Configure method to enable swagger UI
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "aspnetCoreNg API", Version = "v1" });
                options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

                // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new ApiKeyScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Type = "apiKey"
                });
            });



            services.AddScoped<IWebResourceManager, WebResourceManager>();

            var configurations = AppConfigurations.Get(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

            services.Configure<ExamDatabaseSettings>(configurations.GetSection(nameof(ExamDatabaseSettings)));
            // Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
            return services.AddAbp<NivraWebMvcModule>(
                // Configure Log4Net logging
                options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                    f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
                )
            );
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

            app.UseCors(_defaultCorsPolicyName); // Enable CORS!

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (
                    context.Response.StatusCode == 404
                    && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value)
                    && !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/services", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    )
                { context.Request.Path = "/index.html"; await next(); }
            });


            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "defaultWithArea",
                    template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            // app.Map("/spa", l =>
            //    l.UseSpa(spa =>
            //    {
            //        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            //        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            //        spa.Options.SourcePath = "./";

            //        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //        {
            //            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            //        }
            //    })
            //);

            app.UseSwagger();
            //Enable middleware to serve swagger - ui assets(HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AbpZeroTemplate API V1");
            }); //URL: /swagger
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding [DisableValidation] on DTO class did not make any difference, but adding above web method disabled validation.

Comment: can you show your Startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abp wraps only exception thrown in actions with ObjectResult return type by default. e.g. public JsonResult Create();

If your action is return a view result, it is recommended to catch the exception within the action yourself and add to ModelState manually.

see https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#exception-filter

Referring above link

> Exception handling and logging behaviour can be changed using the
>   WrapResult and DontWrapResult attributes for methods and classes.